# Some quasi differential equations

Tags: cv.complex-variables, differential-equations

This question is inspired by the concept of "Differential Inclusion".

The ring of entire holomorphic functions  is denoted by $Hol(\mathbb{C})$.

Is there a complete classification of all $f\in Hol(\mathbb{C})$ such that the $Hol(\mathbb{C})$-module generated by $\{f,f',f'',\ldots,f^{(n)},\ldots\}$ would be equal to the whole ring $Hol(\mathbb{C})$?

Is there a complete classification of all $f\in Hol (\mathbb{C})$ such that the $\mathbb{C}$_ module (or $Hol (\mathbb{C})$_ module generated by $\{f^{(n)}, f^{(n+1)}, \ldots\}$ is independent of $n$?

Comment: For the second question, every solution to linear ordinary differential equations of the form $$ f = \sum_{k = 1}^K \alpha_k f^{(k)} $$ where the $\alpha_k$ are holomorphic functions satisfies your condition, so there are a lot of functions of this type. (How would you even classify all ODEs of the above type?)

Comment: An obvious necessary condition is that $f$ can't have zeros of arbitrarily high order. Maybe I'm too naïve, but to me it feels as if this condition might well be sufficient also.